# Objects for a face book

Tags: java

Consider the following two classes:

```
public class Person<P extends Comparable<P>> {
    
    private List<Person<P>> following = new ArrayList<Person<P>>();
    private List<Person<P>> friends = new ArrayList<Person<P>>();
    private P id;

    public Person(P id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public P getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public List<Person<P>> getFollowing() {
        return following;
    }

    public List<Person<P>> getFriends() {
        return friends;
    }
    
    public boolean isFollowing(Person<P> person) {
        return following.contains(person);
    }


    public void addFriend(Person<P> person) {
        friends.add(person);
    }
}

public class WasteBookController<P extends Comparable<P>> {
    
    List<Person<P>> people = new ArrayList<Person<P>>();
    /**
     * Adds a new member with the given name to the network. 
     */
    public void addPersonToNetwork(P name) {
        people.add(new Person<P>(name));
    }

    /**
     * @preconditions person1 and person2 already exist in the social media network.
     * person1 follows person2 in the social media network.
     */
    public void follow(P person1, P person2) {
        if (person1.equals(person2)) {
            return;
        }

        for (Person<P> member1 : people) {
            if (member1.getId().equals(person1)) {
                for (Person<P> member2 : people) {
                    if (member2.getId().equals(person2)) {
                        List<Person<P>> following = member1.getFollowing();
                        following.add(member2);

                        if (member2.isFollowing(member1)) {
                            member1.addFriend(member2);
                            member2.addFriend(member1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public int getPopularity(P person) {
        Person<P> member = people.stream().filter(p -> p.getId().equals(person)).findFirst().get();
        int popularity = 0;

        for (Person<P> other : people) {
            List<Person<P>> following = other.getFollowing();
            if (following.contains(member)) {
                popularity += 1;
            }
        }

        return popularity;
    }

    public int getFriends(P person) {
        Person<P> member = people.stream().filter(p -> p.getId().equals(person)).findFirst().get();
        return member.getFriends().size();
    }

    /**
     * Returns an iterator to the network (each member)
     * ordered by the given parameter.
     */
    public NetworkIterator<P> getIterator(String orderBy) {
        Comparator<Person<P>> comparator = null;
        if (orderBy.equals("popularity")) {
            comparator = Comparator.comparing(p -> -getPopularity(p.getId()));
        } else if (orderBy.equals("friends")) {
            comparator = Comparator.comparing(p -> -getFriends(p.getId()));
        }

        comparator = comparator.thenComparing(Person::getId);

        return new NetworkIterator<P>(people.stream()
                     .sorted(comparator)
                     .map(Person::getId)
                     .collect(Collectors.toList())
                     .iterator());
    }

    public void switchIteratorComparisonMethod(NetworkIterator<P> iter, String orderBy) {
        // TODO Part d)
    }
}
```

I want to identify if there are any design issues or code smells in this.

It's for a backend implementation for a face book where people can have followers and friends.

A person cannot follow itself, and if a person1 follows person2 and person2 follows person1, they are friends.

I am looking for some ways to improve it.

`P extends Comparable<P>` - Since I want the IDs to be comparable, I did this.  But I am not sure if this is ideal.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Did you test any of this? It seems like a couple of library functions without implementation.

Comment: In my opinion the template parameter `P` could be renamed as `PersonIdType`, it would be more insightful when re-reading the code.

Comment: Template parameters should only have a single letter names, otherwise they look like concrete class names. If P should be a PersonIdType then it should be defined as <P extends PersonIdType>

Answer (score 2):

Surely, as you are aware of the term *code smell*, you have reads this? https://blog.codinghorror.com/code-smells/

The first stench I sense is that you *indecently expose* the internal data structures of `Person` by returning the list instances directly from `getFollowing` and `getFriends`. This allows anyone to modify their content without any oversight leading in "easy to make, hard to find" ways of breaking the application data structures.

Related to that, you define a single manipulation method `addFriend` for modifying the `friends`-list and a single query method `isFollowing`. There is no clear distinction on who is responsible for controlling the manipulation of the data structures or what manipulation and query operations should be available to the lists. Is the responsibility on `Person`, `WasteBookController` or whoever gets a handle to the lists?

The `WasteBookController`, as it is now, gives out all the scents that make me expect it to become a monolith, a *large class*, loaded with [every possible responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle).

You probably wil eventually want to store more information about relationship between two accounts (like when it was created, etc). Remember that secretly hoarding data from your users and selling it is the central business plan of the platform you are creating. For that you cannot just store lists of direct object references to `People`. You need classes for `Friendship` and `Following`. Then you would need a class for `Blocked` accounts. Maybe at this point it becomes easier to create a `Relationship` class with properties indicating the aforementioned statuses.

You represent network with a field named `people`. That is *inconsistent naming*.